Make dictionary object globally available
I am trying to call a function and reference dictionary data.
How do I declare the vrnHistory dictionary as a global resource?
I stripped the code down but the basics are below.
I want the MsgBox to display the string in A1.
Public Sub GlobalTest()
    Set vrnHistory = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vrnHistory.Add "A1", "This is dictionary Data for global share"
    FN_GlobalTest
End Sub

Public Function FN_GlobalTest()          
    MsgBox "Within Function called from SUB " & vrnHistory("A1")
End Function


Dim your vrnHistory variable Public outside of the Sub. Right now you are not declaring it at all, you are just setting it, so it assumes you want it to be local.

The problem with this approach is that you need to guarantee that GlobalTest is run before you access vrnHistory.

As braX wrote, the variable vrnHistory is a local variable in GlobalTest and another local variable in FN_GlobalTest. Those are different variables (with the same name, but that doesn't matter), and both variables live only as long as the routine is executed.
The quick solution is to declare the variable outside of the code of your two routines at the top of the module:
Dim vrnHistory as Object

Public Sub GlobalTest()
    Set vrnHistory = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vrnHistory.Add "A1", "This is dictionary Data for global share"
    FN_GlobalTest
End Sub

Public Function FN_GlobalTest()       
    MsgBox "Within Function called from SUB " & vrnHistory("A1")
End Function

As the variable is Global, it is not destroyed after GlobalTest finishes, and you can use it everywhere in your code. All good. All?
With that setup, you need to ensure that GlobalTest is always called first, but never again. If it is not called first, your dictionary will stay uninitialized (Nothing) and you will get a runtime error. If it is called multiple times, it will create a new dictionary every time (and the content of the previous dictionary is gone forever).
This is one of the reasons that global variables are not really programmers best friends. Especially in larger projects it will get more and more difficult to keep track what happens to them.
So instead of using a global variable, I usually write a simple function. This function uses a static variable. Static variables are not destroyed when the routine ends, but they are still local to the routine. The function will create a new dictionary only if it wasn't created before.
Public Function vrnHistory() 
    Static dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If
    Set vrnHistory = dict 
End Function

Now you can access the dictionary in any order.
